# Bookshelf.JS | How to use where and orWhere in query

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

BookshelfJS has the following example for using 'query':

```
model
  .query({where: {other_id: '5'}, orWhere: {key: 'value'}})
  .fetch()
  .then(function(model) {
    ...
  });
```

Is it okay to do the following:

```
var whereObj = {
  'key1':'value1',
  'key2':'value2'
};

model
  .query({where: whereObj, orWhere: {key: 'value'}})
  .fetch()
  .then(function(model) {
    ...
  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options:

**Use a callback**

```
.query(function (qb) {
    qb.where(other_id, '5')
        .orWhere('key', 'value');
});
```

**Use an object**

```
.query({
    where: { other_id: '5' },
    orWhere: { key: 'value' }
})
```

Comment: So begin with .orWhere() instead of .where()? Doesn't sound intuitive. :( Feels like it should be the other way around.

Comment: Oh, sorry. That was an error in the callback example - start with `where`. `orWhere` defaults to `where` if it is the first `*where` statement.

Answer (score 13):

For more complex queries, you can use this:

```
.query(function(qb) {
                    qb.select('*');
                    qb.where(function () {
                        this.where('attr1', 1);
                        this.where('attr2','in' , [1,2,3]);
                    });
                    qb.orWhere(function () {
                        this.where('attr1', 2);
                        this.where('attr2','in' , [4,5,6]);
                    });
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [bookshelf-eloquent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-eloquent) extension which exposes many of the Knex.js functions directly on the bookshelf model. Your code would be simplified to something like this:

```
let result = await Model.where({other_id: 5}).orWhere('key', 'value').fetch();
```

Comment: Great extension. Thanks!